# require.js optimizer app.build.js documentation wanted

Tags: javascript, documentation, requirejs, r.js

Optimization script for RequireJS is configured by app.build.js file (it's just a convention)
This file defines how the project is built.

Basic usage of this file is described here: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject

But I was unable to find any documentation on avaliable options. I was only able to find examples allowing me to deduce some of the options I am surrently using.

Is there any documentation except the page I just linked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is listed under "All configuration options", at http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#options.

The documented `example.build.js` is at https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I expected a table with all configurations and possible values, but that'll do :)